# How to store text of alertView in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uialertview

I was hoping someone could help me with storing the data inputted into my alertView textField to firebase firestore. I have a collection called "HelpRequests" and I want the information to be stored in that collection. Below is the code for the alert.

```
@objc func alertTapped(sender:UIButton!){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Report an issue", message: "Please allow 24hour to respond", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default) { (action) in

        if let te = alert.textFields?.first?.text , te.count > 0 {
        }

    })
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        // Respond to user selection of the action.
    })

    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = ""
    }
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: Aside from that: did you try anything yet? If not, I'd recommend starting with: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: Thanks, i managed to fix it after I posted this